# Trouble with Ekko-Lightbox playing YouTube videos/linked images not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

I'm trying to learn/figure out how to successfully play a youtube video within a Bootstrap modal with ekko-lightbox plugin attributes. I've managed to get the Vimeo link to work, but the YouTube link will not retrieve the video, and the button images (external links) do not appear. My work files are saved on my desktop/locally. Do I need to upload my files to an ISP in order for the YouTube and image links to work? I would also like to know how to make the videos play in the modal without having to rely on the internet. That way if I want to present a website concept and there is no internet access, I can still have functionality.

Here is the code as it appears in my index file. Only the Vimeo video link and static waterfall image links work. The button image links do not appear either. Please help!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mixed Lightbox Gallery in Bootstrap</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/ekko-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">


                    <h3 class="page-header" id="mixed-gallery">Mixed gallery</h3>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
                            <div class="row">
                                <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6mFF3VmVAs" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="mixedgallery" class="col-sm-4">
                                    <img src="//i1.ytimg.com/vi/yP11r5n5RNg/mqdefault.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                                </a>
                                <a href="http://41.media.tumblr.com/9d3e6a9c89a856a2ad0be3ab4ca598b2/tumblr_mrn3dc10Wa1r1thfzo4_1280.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="mixedgallery" class="col-sm-4">
                                    <img src="//41.media.tumblr.com/9d3e6a9c89a856a2ad0be3ab4ca598b2/tumblr_mrn3dc10Wa1r1thfzo4_1280.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                                </a>
                                <a href="http://vimeo.com/80629469" data-remote="http://player.vimeo.com/video/80629469" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="mixedgallery" class="col-sm-4">
                                    <img src="//b.vimeocdn.com/ts/458/070/458070637_200.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ekko-lightbox.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function ($) {
                // delegate calls to data-toggle="lightbox"
                $(document).delegate('*[data-toggle="lightbox"]:not([data-gallery="navigateTo"])', 'click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return $(this).ekkoLightbox({
                        onShown: function() {
                            if (window.console) {
                                return console.log('Checking our the events huh?');
                            }
                        },
                        onNavigate: function(direction, itemIndex) {
                            if (window.console) {
                                return console.log('Navigating '+direction+'. Current item: '+itemIndex);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

                //Programatically call
                $('#open-image').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).ekkoLightbox();
                });
                $('#open-youtube').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).ekkoLightbox();
                });

                // navigateTo
                $(document).delegate('*[data-gallery="navigateTo"]', 'click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var lb;
                    return $(this).ekkoLightbox({
                        onShown: function() {

                            lb = this;

                            $(lb.modal_content).on('click', '.modal-footer a', function(e) {

                                e.preventDefault();
                                lb.navigateTo(2);

                            });

                        }
                    });
                });


            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to have your files on a server rather than locally for the Youtube videos and images to work. I experienced this as well and by inspecting the code I saw that the way the javascript was written, those assets are called as file:// rather than http:// when working locally. I thought maybe it had to do with relative links, but it's true even when using absolute URLs.

Since Youtube is dependent on an internet connection, I can't think of a way to load those videos without internet. Try using a locally stored video instead of Youtube video, if you're just concepting something out.